# what does $_GET['2020'] mean?

Tags: php, http

a challenge like this $_GET['2020'] snippet boring me a long time, i want to know how this work, but do not know which keywords to search, maybe how the parameter works?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET` reads querystring parameters from the URL. So if someone goes to your PHP script with a URL like `http://servername/scriptname.php?2020=ABC` then when the PHP script runs, the variable `$_GET['2020']` will contain the value `ABC`.

More info is available in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: thx,make some sense and also will check the link